# Which flights to the US don't permit passengers to bring water or other liquid on board (even if purchased after the security checkpoint)?

Tags: usa, air-travel, international-travel, airport-security

Flights from Lima to Houston don't allow passengers to bring water on board (even if purchased after the security checkpoint):

[image]

They do screen passengers' carry-on baggage right before boarding.

Which flights to the US don't permit passengers to bring water or other liquid on board (even if purchased after the security checkpoint)? Does that apply to any international flight to the US nowadays? Or only from some airports or countries?

Comment: Rules like this are usually set by the country of departure.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, it seems to be the same question indeed!